# LINQ Lambda group by multiple columns following by select multiple columns

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Lets assume we have some data in a table:

Id  OrderNr   Name  Date

1 1      John  2011-01-01

2      1      John  2012-01-01

3      2      Paul  2011-02-02

I want to use linq (lambda expressions) to group by OrderNr and Name and select OrderNr, Name and First occuring Date. So the result should be:

OrderNr Name Date

1       John 2011-01-01

2       Paul 2011-02-02

How should this be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
var results1 = (from t in DB.Table
                group t by new { t.OrderN, t.Name } into grp
                select new
                {
                    OrderN = grp.Key.OrderN,
                    Name = grp.Key.Name,
                    FirstDate = grp.FirstOrDefault().Date
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Did almost the same, but using .First() and it didn't work either way. Sql profiler shows an error related to the ORM being used on the project. Thank you for your answer, the problem must be related to other topic.